# In Cakephp when using Ajax to edit a row then clicking edit again it redirects instead of calling the ajax again

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp-3.0

In my Cakephp app clicking edit on a row brings up a modal to edit it.  You edit and submit it and it updates the row as expected.  Now if you click on the row to edit it again it redirects to the edit controller instead of bringing the modal back up.

Example row:

```
<td>123 Main Street</td>
<td>Line2 Empty</td>
<td>Beverly Hills</td>
<td>CA</td>
<td>90210</td>
<td>US</td>
<td class="actions">
<a href="/addresses/view_ajax" rel="modal:open">View</a>
<a href="/addresses/edit_ajax/1" id="edit-1" class="ajax edit">Edit</a>
</td>
```

Ajax/Jquery code:

```
$('.ajax').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ajaxId = $(this).attr('id');
    ajaxClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        success: function(html, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (ajaxClass == "ajax delete") {
                var tr = $('#' + ajaxId).closest('tr')
                tr.css("background-color", "#FF3700");
                tr.fadeOut(400, function() {
                    tr.remove();
                });
                return false;
            } else {
                ajaxModal(ajaxId, html, myBaseUrl, ajaxClass);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (jqXHR.status == 403) {
                window.location.replace("<?= $this->Url->build('/') ?>");
            }
        }
    });
});

function ajaxModal(element, html, myBaseUrl, ajaxClass) {
    $(html).appendTo('body').modal();
    masks();
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (validate()) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: $('#' + element).attr('href'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: $("form").serialize(),
                success: function(newHTML, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $.modal.close();
                    //console.log(ajaxClass);
                    if (ajaxClass == "ajax edit") {
                        $('#' + element).closest('tr').empty().append(newHTML);
                    } else {
                        console.log('here');
                        //$('#' + element).closest('table').after("<tr>" + newHTML + "</tr>");  
                    }

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (jqXHR.status == 403) {
                        window.location.replace(myBaseUrl + "login");
                    }
                    if (jqXHR.status == 400) {
                        edit(element, jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

What am I missing that would cause this?

Comment: Is the ajax class definitely being added to the link in the result? Is there some JavaScript bug happening during this that is causing all further JavaScript to be skipped? Just a couple of thoughts of places to look...

Comment: Thanks Greg, I'll check that.  It was also pointed out to me (and it seems very obvious now) that I probably should not be using a link here.  That a button or some other element with a data attribute would be better suited for this situation, since it shouldn't cause a redirect.